# How to postion the text in Jumbotron-Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: css, html, css-selectors

I can't position my text on `top` in `jumbotron`.

Here is my Code,

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="jumbotron" style="text-align:center; background-image: url(img/propdev.jpg); background-size: cover; height: 30%;">
  <div class="container">
    <h2 id="prop_dev"> Are You a  Property Developer?</h2>
    <div id="raise" class="btn-group btn-group-lg" role="group">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Raise Funding</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the output,
   [Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PeipP.png)

I need to make the text and button on top of the image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added `padding-top:0px` to your inline style to the div which you gave the class "jumbotron"

Now the distance that it has from the top is the padding of the class container, which is within the jumbotron. If you want to remove that too, add the `padding-top:0px;` to that too.

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="jumbotron" style="text-align:center; background-image: url(img/propdev.jpg); background-size: cover; height: 30%; padding-top:0px;">
  <div class="container" style="margin-top:0px !important;">
    <h2 id="prop_dev"> Are You a  Property Developer?</h2>
    <div id="raise" class="btn-group btn-group-lg" role="group">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Raise Funding</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could I get an upvote too? @MuhammadUsman  I know it sounds a little greedy but still :D

Comment: Yeaah, here is the deal,i upvote your answer and you upvote my question XD

Answer (score 1):

Add/Remove padding from jumbotron to position vertically

```css
div.jumbotron{
  padding-top:60px;
  }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="jumbotron" style="text-align:center; background-image: url(img/propdev.jpg); background-size: cover; height: 30%;">
  <div class="container">
    <h2 id="prop_dev"> Are You a  Property Developer?</h2>
    <div id="raise" class="btn-group btn-group-lg" role="group">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Raise Funding</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```